# Calling recv() the second time returns positive int, but reads nothing into buffer

Tags: c++

I want to send a string from a server to a client. To account for the case that the string is bigger than the buffer that the client reads into, I send a byte count to the client before the actual string. Then on the client side, I split the read operation into multiple recv() calls if needed.

Server:

```
// Send byte count to client so it knows how much data to expect
strcpy(buffer, std::to_string(string_size).c_str());

int result{ send(socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0) };

// Send actual data
unsigned int bytes_to_send{ sizeof(s) };
while (bytes_to_send > 0) {

    send_bytes = std::min(buffer_size, bytes_to_send);

    strcpy(buffer, s.substr(0, send_bytes).c_str());

    result = send(socket, buffer, send_bytes, 0);

    if (s.size() > send_bytes) {
        s = s.substr(send_bytes, s.size() - send_bytes);
    }
    bytes_to_send -= send_bytes;
    return_int += send_bytes;
```

(In the actual code, I check result to see whether send() succeeded)

Client:

```
result = recv(socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0);
count = std::stoi(buffer);

while(count > 0){
    read_bytes = std::min(count, buffer_size);
    result = recv(socket, buffer, read_bytes, 0);
    if(result < 1 ) {
        // throw exception
    }else{
        return_string += buffer;
    }
    count -= read_bytes;
```

What I expected:

- Client blocks on first recv() call until server sends byte count
- Client proceeds until second recv() call, then blocks until server sends string

What actually happens:

- Client blocks on first recv() call until server sends byte count
- Client does not block on second recv() call. recv() return value is equal to read_bytes, but does not fill the buffer with anything

Thanks in advance for any help with this

Comment: a message sent in one statement may not be received in one statement, so even the length you send may be received in two pakets (unlikely but not forbidden by anything....

Comment: And also: did you check if the socket is blocking? (although it should return something different then...)

Comment: the length is received correctly by the client. it attempts to read n bytes in the second recv() call, n being the byte count that has been submitted before

Comment: I thought that the program is supposed to wait for the recv() call when the socket is blocking, e.g. not continue until there is something to read

Comment: The problem you have is that `send` is free to buffer and send whatever it wants. `recv` likewise will only get what `send` sends. Your assessment is correct on what happens if `send` sends the byte count in one transmission and then collects bytes in another and then sends only those bytes, but that's not really how it works. `send` is free to buffer data until it has enough data to justify a `send`. This prevents *rabbit-pellet-fragmentation* of data and dramatically decreases the number of sends and receives required. (it doesn't make it any easier on the programmer).

Comment: Highly recommend [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). The 2nd half goes into several approaches to handle this type of back and forth communication in a rational way as well as some of the advance ways of telling the other side what is coming by either header injection or out-of-stream data. Well worth the read.

Comment: TCP knows nothing about what you consider a message. The only guarantee you get is the bytes you send are received in the same order or the connection dies trying. When you get them is unspecified. How many bytes you get at a time is unspecified. You must make sure you got all of any data you are expecting and you need to make sure that if you read too much you preserve it for the next message to consume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code.

`strcpy(buffer, std::to_string(string_size).c_str());` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen.

`send(socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0)` - you did not set `buffer_size` to the number of bytes copied into `buffer` by `strcpy()`.  It looks like you are sending the entire `buffer` without regard to how many bytes it is actually holding.

`sizeof(s)` does not give you the number of characters in a `std::string`.  It gives you the byte size of the `std::string` class itself, which is not the same thing. You need to use the string's `size()` or `length()` method to get the proper number of characters.

TCP is a byte stream, there is no 1-to-1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()`.  Both can report fewer bytes were processed than requested, but you are not accounting for that properly.

You are completely ignoring the return value of `send()`, assuming that all requested bytes have been sent in full on each call, when in actuality fewer bytes may have been sent, or none at all.  On the 1st call, you are not accounting for the possibility that the entire size string may not be sent in 1 call and may need to be looped.  Inside of the loop, you are completely ignoring the return value of `send()` for purposes of looping.

Likewise, you are ignoring the return value of `recv()` on the 1st call, assuming the entire string size is received in 1 call, without regard to how many characters are actually in the string size.  Inside the loop, you are paying attention to the return value of `recv()` for purposes of looping, except that you are not accounting for the possibility that `recv()` returns 0 on a graceful disconnect.  You are not breaking your loop if that happens.

It is good that you want to send the string's size before sending its content.  However, you are sending the size as another variable-length string, which really defeats the purpose of sending a size at all.  You should send the size using a fixed-length integer in binary form instead.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
void send_raw(int socket, const void *buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
    const char *ptr = (const char*) buffer;
    while (buffer_size > 0) {
        int sent = send(socket, ptr, buffer_size, 0);
        if (sent < 0) {
            // throw exception
        }
        ptr += sent;
        buffer_size -= sent;
    }
}

void send_u32(int socket, uint32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    send_raw(socket, &value, sizeof(value));
}

...

// Send byte count to client so it knows how much data to expect
send_u32(socket, s.size());

// Send actual data
send_raw(socket, s.c_str(), s.size());
```

```cpp
void recv_raw(int socket, void *buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
    char *ptr = (char*) buffer;
    while (buffer_size > 0) {
        int recvd = recv(socket, ptr, buffer_size, 0);
        if (recvd <= 0) {
            // throw exception
        }
        ptr += recvd;
        buffer_size -= recvd;
    }
}

uint32_t recv_u32(int socket)
{
    uint32_t value;
    recv_raw(socket, &value, sizeof(value));
    return ntohl(value);
}

...

size_t count = recv_u32(socket);
return_string.resize(count);
recv_raw(socket, &return_string[0], count);
```

However, if you really want to stick with sending the string size as another string, you need to delimit it, such as sending its null terminator, eg:

```cpp
// Send byte count to client so it knows how much data to expect
std::string size_buffer = std::to_string(s.size());
send_raw(socket, size_buffer.c_str(), size_buffer.size()+1);

// Send actual data
send_raw(socket, s.c_str(), s.size());
```

```cpp
std::string size_buffer;
char ch;

do {
    recv_raw(socket, &ch, 1);
    if (ch == '\0') break;
    size_buffer += ch;
}
while (true);

size_t count = std::stoi(size_buffer);
return_string.resize(count);
recv_raw(socket, &return_string[0], count);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this wholesome answer, I am gonna try and refactor my code accordingly tomorrow. I'll keep you updated

Comment: I still dont undestand how recv() can return a positive integer, lets say 30, without actually reading 30 bytes into the specified buffer though. Am I missing something here? Is there a scenario where read would return a positive int without updating the buffer?

Comment: "*I still dont undestand how recv() can return a positive integer, lets say 30, without actually reading 30 bytes into the specified buffer though*" - it can't. The return value is the *actual* number of bytes read int* the buffer. You are most likely simply interpreting the contents of the buffer incorrectly. "*Am I missing something here?*" - yes. "*Is there a scenario where read would return a positive int without updating the buffer?*" - no.

Comment: In your example, you use dynamic buffer sizes. Are there any cons to using dynamic buffer sizes as opposed to static ones? Considering the data sent is relatively big

Comment: @relativity_face which "dynamic buffer sizes" are you referring to exactly?

Comment: Sorry if I used the wrong terminology, I am pretty new to network programming ( as you probably guessed) . What I mean is, I often see functions where data that is sent is split up into chunks of a fixed size. In your example, the send_raw function takes a variable parameter "buffer_size", which is passed to the subsequently called send() function's parameter "len". I often see a step in between in other functions, asserting that "len" doesnt exceed a certain "max buffer size", e.g. len = std::min(MAX_BUFFER, size_of_my_data). That is what I mean with fixed vs dynamic buffer size.

Comment: @relativity_face the code I provided is sending the caller's data as-is directly from its original memory, and receiving directly onto the caller's variables, so the functions do not need to copy data into/from a fixed buffer. They just  need to know the full size of the data, and then send/receive as much as they can on each call to `send()`/`recv()`. However, there is nothing stopping you from using an intermediate buffer if you really want to, but it is unnecessary in this particular example, but there are other scenarios where extra buffering may be useful (ie, asynchronous I/O, etc) .

Answer (score -1):

You can add MSG_WAITALL to the recv() flags and do only one read.

Comment: That won't solve any of the problems in the OP's code